# Doubt in a graph theory paper of Lovasz

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am reading from the paper "Product Dimension of Graphs" by Lovasz, Nesetril and Pultr (available [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589568090043X)). I have a doubt in the proof of Lemma 4.2 which establishes that for a graphs $G$ with order $n\ge 5$ and $\Delta(G^c)=n-2$ the product dimension is at most $n-2$.

The authors start by letting $H=G^c$. They let $a$ be the vertex of degree $\Delta (G^c)$ in $G^c$. Now $a$ is not adjacent to all other vertices in $G^c$ for then $\Delta(G^c)$ would have been $n-1$, which is against the hypothesis. So, there exists exactly one vertex $b$ such that $ab$ is not an edge in $G^c$.

Now I believe at this point there is a typographical error. The authors state:

> Denote by $H'$ resp. $H^*$ the subgraphs of $H$ spanned by
>   $V(H)\setminus \{a,b\}$.

I believe this should be:

> Let $H'$ be the subgraph of $G^c$ induced by all the vertices except
>   $a$. Also let $H^*$ be the subgraph of $G^c$ induced by all the
>   vertices except $a$ and $b$.

Next they consider three cases:

Case A: $H^*$ has no edges.

Case B: $H^*$ has edges and the largest degree vertex of $H^*$ has degree at most $n-3$.

Case C: $H^*$ has edges and the largest degree vertex of $H^*$ has degree equal to $n-2$.

In Case A, the authors state that "obviously $\dim G\le n-2$". I do not understand this. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your interpretation that $H'$ is the subgraph of $H$ induced by $V(H) \setminus \{a\}$ and $H^*$ is the subgraph of $H$ induced by $V(H) \setminus \{a,b\}$. In support of this, note that the three cases are stated as

- $H^*$ is discrete (has no edges),
- $H^*$ is not discrete and $\Delta(H') \le n-3$,
- $H^*$ is not discrete and $\Delta(H') = n-2$.

The third case is only possible if $H'$ has at least $n-1$ vertices, and in the third case, it is concluded that $d_H(b) = n-2$, which only follows if $H'$ includes the vertex $b$.

(The argument there is that in $H'$, no vertex other than $b$ can have degree $n-2$, because then it has degree $n-1$ in $H$, being also adjacent to $a$. But $\Delta(H) = n-2$. Therefore, if $\Delta(H') = n-2$, then it must be $b$ that has degree $n-2$ in $H'$, and since $ab \notin E(H)$, $b$ has degree $n-2$ in $H$ as well.)

---

Now on to your main question. In the first case, where $H^*$ has no edges, we know that $H = G^c$ has the following structure:

- Vertices $a$, $b$, and $v_1, \dots, v_{n-2}$.
- Edges $av_1, \dots, av_{n-2}$ and $bv_1, \dots, bv_k$ for some $0 \le k \le n-2$.

This is triangle-free, so by Proposition 2.3 in the paper, the dimension of $G$ is determined entirely by the edge chromatic number of $H$. If $\chi'(H) \le 1$, then $\dim G = \chi'(H) + 1$, and if $\chi'(H) \ge 2$, then $\dim G = \chi'(H)$.

To edge-color $H$, we must begin by coloring $av_1, \dots, av_{n-2}$ using $n-2$ distinct colors (since they all share the endpoint $a$). We can avoid using any more colors by coloring $bv_i$ the same color as $av_{i+1}$ (and, if we get all the way up to $bv_{n-2}$, coloring it the same color as $av_1$). Therefore $\chi'(H) = n-2$, and we conclude $\dim G = n-2$. (The lemma assumes $n \ge 5$, so in particular $\chi'(H) \ge 2$.)

I don't know if this is supposed to count as obvious, or if it's the intended argument, but at least it resolves the issue.

Comment: A minor quibble: $k$ runs from $0$ to $n-2$, and not $1$ to $n-2$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The graph dimension, $\dim(G)$, is defined as the smallest dimension in which the graph has a unit-distance representation.  If $H^*$ has no edges, then $G^c$ has only edges connecting vertices to $a$ or $b$ or both.  So, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, place $a$ and $b$ at $(\pm 1/2, 0, 0)$, and all the other nodes anywhere on the circle $(0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin\theta, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos\theta)$.  Then you have a unit-distance representation of $G^c$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, showing that $\dim(G) \le 3 \le n-2$.

---

*Edit:*
I'm leaving the above answer; but as pointed out in the comment, the definition of $\dim$ in the referenced paper is somewhat different.  In the paper, the graph dimension $\dim(G)$ is the least $n$ such that $G$ can be embedded into ${\bf N}^n$, where ${\bf N}$ is the complete graph with natural numbers as vertices.  Again note that if $H^*$ has no edges, then $G^c$ has only edges connecting vertices to $a$ or $b$ or both.  Put $a$ at $(1,1,1)$.  If $a$ and $b$ are connected, put $b$ at $(2,2,2)$; otherwise put $b$ at $(1,2,2)$.  (That is, the first coordinate is used to decide if $a$ and $b$ are connected.)  Finally, put each $c\not\in\{a, b\}$ at $(m_c,a_c,b_c)$, where $m_c=3,4,5,\ldots$ (different for each $c$), and $a_c=1$ or $2$ or $3$ if $c$ is connected to just $b$, just $a$, or both, and $b_c=1$ or $2$ or $3$ if $c$ is connected to just $a$, just $b$, or both.  As this is an embedding of $G^c$ in ${\bf N}^3$, we have $\dim(G)\le 3 \le n-2$.

Comment: The dimension in this paper and what you are calling as dimension is different.

Comment: Your second answer also doesn't work. If $a$ has label $(1,1,1)$ and $c$ is not adjacent to $a$, then the label of $c$ must be of the form $(x,y,1)$ or $(x,1,z)$ or $(1,y,z)$. Suppose that $G$ has four vertices not adjacent to $a$. Then two of them must have a $1$ in the same position, which means that they cannot be adjacent in $G$, so the labeling is only valid if they are adjacent in $G^c$. This contradicts the assumption that there are no edges in $H^*$.

Comment: In particular, there is an easy argument that the dimension (as defined in the paper) is *at least* $n-2$. You have $n-2$ vertices not adjacent to $a$, so they must agree with $a$ in some coordinate. But they are all adjacent to each other, so they must differ in all coordinates. Therefore two of them can't agree with $a$ in the same coordinate: so there must be at least $n-2$ coordinates for them to agree with $a$ in.